# How to configure LDAP client without Yast - SLES 11 SP3

Tags: ldap, authentication, command-line-interface, sles11

I'm configuring an LDAP client in a large number of Suse servers. The only way that I know to do this is using Yast, and this way is slow. I can't find another way.

I did it on RHEL, Debian, and others Linux distributions , but I can't map all files that was modifies by Yast on Suse.

Comment: Is it openLDAP? Could add it to an autoYast config and deploy that way -https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/singlehtml/book_autoyast/book_autoyast.html

Comment: I tried to do that, but the autoyast crash some times, I was versioned all files in the /etc/ directory to map modifications that was made by Yast. Now, I can see a light at the end of the tunnel, that is not the and, I keep trying.